# Regex: Select the particular html tag that contains this word, and that has nothing left after it

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have these two tags:

`<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership: Do you love me?</p>`

and this one:

`<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership: </p>`

So, I have more then 2000 html files. And I want to find and select only the second example, the html tag that contains this word "Leadership:", and that has nothing left after it.

can anyone help me?

I try this, but is not to good: `<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership: \S*\s*</p>`

Comment: What tools have you tried? What would you like to do with files that contain this tag?

Comment: I want to find missing/incomplete lines :)

Comment: I try this `<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership: \S*\s*</p>` but must be a little bip update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all the files are inside one folder, use the notepad++ menu of
*Search > Find in files...* and search for this regex pattern:

```
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership:\s*</p>
```

Ensure that you have set "Search Mode" to "Regular expression"
and "Directory" to your folder.

Click "Find All" to search.